# Problema com alocacao de memoria pela segunda vez

Tags: c

bom, o programa funciona corretamente no primeiro loop for, porem no segundo ele trava ao tentar alocar "q" pela segunda vez.
segue parte do codigo:

```
void Insere(Poligono p, double x, double y){
    Poligono q;
    q = (Poligono)malloc(sizeof(Poligono));
    printf("teste\n");
    q->x = x;
    q->y = y;
    q->prox = p->prox;
    p->prox = q;
}
int main(){
    int vertices, i;
    double x, y;
    Poligono p = Cuca();//cabeca
    printf("Vertices: ");
    scanf(" %d", &vertices);
    for(i = 0; i < vertices; i++){
        printf("Coordenadas: ");
        scanf(" %f %f", &x, &y);
        Insere(p, x, y);
    }
    ImprimeLista(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: posso tentar, mas a unica diferenca entre malloc e calloc e q o calloc aloca e "poe" zero nas posicoes n ?

Comment: Não sei se é a causa de seu problema mas como você declarou suas variáveis x e y como double a especificação de formato na função scanf deveria se %lf.

Comment: @michel, sem o código completo fica difícil dizer qual o erro. O que eu pude notar é que o seu `malloc` está errado. Eu estou supondo que `Poligono` deve ser um `typedef` para `struct poligono*`. Se esse é o caso, `malloc(Poligono)` estará reservando espaço na memória apenas para armazenar um ponteiro, não para armazenar a estrutura `struct poligono`. O certo seria `q = (Poligono)malloc(sizeof(struct poligono))`

Comment: era isso msm, depois de um tempo pesquisando descobri isso, mt obrigado, vou comecar a postar o codigo inteiro de agr em diante, sou novo por aqui :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variável `q` não é um ponteiro para struct Poligono.
Analisando seu código você tem o head(cuca) mas não está utilizando ponteiros em lugar nenhum no código.

No meu entendimento deveria ser algo assim

```
Poligono *p = Cuca();
```

```
void Insere(Poligono *p, double x, double y){
    Poligono *q = malloc(sizeof(Poligono));
```

O seu `prox` dentro da struct Poligono também tem que ser um ponteiro.

Comment: obrigado :D, me ajudou mt